# How to stop scrapy from logging?

Tags: python, logging, scrapy

I am calling a `Scrapy` based crawler from a bigger framework. During the crawl 
`Scrapy` logs all events. After the crawl scrapy should stop logging and the calling framework should take over the logging duty and printing to standard out again.

**How to can I stop `Scrapy` from dominating all logs and pass it back to my framework?**

**How to manage several loggers in Python?**

**Update:** I added `crawler.spider.settings.overrides['LOG_ENABLED'] = False` to my crawler. Scrapy keeps on preventing me to print to standard out.

Answer (score 0):

Change [`LOG_ENABLED`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#log-enabled) setting to `False`.

Comment: I added this line of code: `crawler.spider.settings.overrides['LOG_ENABLED'] = False`. It keeps on executing as I know from a failed assertion. However, it does not print to standard out.